# symfony referer with locale

Tags: symfony, locale, translate, referer

i try simply to redirect page last see with argument location (us,fr,es,it,etc...)

it's work perfectly with href=fr, or href=it

but if i'm on login page, that redirect in index...

so i try in controller make that, but not result

```
 #[Route( '/change_locale/{localisation}', name: 'change_locale', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function changeLocale( string $localisation, Request $request)
{
    // On revient sur la page précédente
    return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'),302,['_locale' => $localisation]);
}
```

someone can help me?

i try to help me, i have try lot of code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it's very clear dear bot, i can't more explain because it's like water transparent